# Laravel route does not working inside group

Tags: php, laravel

I have group of middleware in which I want to add the route but it does not working, the route group is following

```
Route::group(
    [
        'domain'    => 'admin.'.env('APP_DOMAIN'),
        'as'        => 'admin.'
    ],
    function () {

         Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
             /* I am trying to add route here */
         });
    })
```

I need to add following route

```
Route::post('/dashboard/tokens-sale-record','Admin\DashboardController@totalSaleForChart')->name('tokensSaleRecords');
```

When I add this route inside above group then it is not working but when I add outside it is working fine. I am using route in ajax.

Can someone kindly let me know what is the issue. I would like to appreciate.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you just get a 404 or is there an exception?

Comment: @Jerodev exactly 404

Answer (score 0):

Because you already defined `Admin\` namespace path in parent group. That's way, You don't use `Admin` again namespace path in routes in the group.

Can you try following route define.

`Route::post('/dashboard/tokens-sale-record','DashboardController@totalSaleForChart')->name('tokensSaleRecords');`

If you using again `Admin\Dashboard`, Laravel searching it DashboardController as the Admin\Admin\DashboardController.

Comment: FYI; If a comment is helpful, your confirmation to a helpful comment is important for commentator and who want make new comment. But it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::group(
[
    'domain'    => 'admin.'.env('APP_DOMAIN'),
    'as'        => 'admin.'
],
function () {

     Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin'], function() {
         Route::post('/dashboard/tokens-sale-record','DashboardController@totalSaleForChart')->name('tokensSaleRecords');

     });
});
```

There is no need to write admin before calling controller. It will check for Admin\Admin\DashboardController.

If you are not able to find right route then use `php artisan route:list | grep tokens-sale-record` to check for the right route.